# Program adding contacts on the emulator does not add contacts on the HTC Desire

Tags: android, android-emulator, contacts

I want to write a program to automatically generate the contacts. I also use a special service to add account on emulator. The same account is used on the telephone. 
Below is my code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "localhost");
values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "PC Sync");
Uri rawContactUri = getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);
long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);             

values.clear();
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, Gname);
values.put(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, Fname);
values.put(StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME, Mname);
getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

The program is working on emulator and adds contacts, but on HTC the program  only process adding no contacts. 
I can't understand what the problem can be.

Comment: You may find http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/44f3a999f4741ccd?pli=1 helpful, potentially.

Comment: Thank you, Yoni, I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: Yes, there aren't necessary account on phone. The problem was solved by changing contacts visibility options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the solution [Android: Enable imported account contacts programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825577/android-enable-imported-account-contacts-programmatically). You should specify UNGROUPED_VISIBLE=1 to make new contacts visible.