# how to sync contacts automatically on adding an account?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have built an account and the sync works fine . But the problem is I have to explicitly check the `sync contacts` `checkbox` to trigger the `sync adapter`. Is there any way to automate it and have it checked automatically on account adding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research with stachoverflow and android docs, The below code does the Trick

> ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account,
> ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);

Tested on android version ics and above.

Courtesy :
[GENIUS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545592/3444930)

Answer (score 1):

To sync automatically use:

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);
```

To sync periodically use:

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY, SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS);
```

Following documentation demonstrating different ways of running the sync:
[Running a Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html)